# Overlay on top of app

Tags: ios

Here is the top of my app:
[image: i.imgur.com/XUjK1TK.jpg]

Here how it suppose to be:
[image: i.imgur.com/HsQjPh8.jpg]

Here in multitasking:

[image]

You can see a sort of black transparent rectangle in top of the app what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using Storyboard or programmatically?

Comment: I have no idea what story board or programmatically, the only customization I have is this code @implementation RootViewController - (void)loadView {         self.view = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]] autorelease];         self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

Comment: "Respring"? are you developing for a jailbroken device?

Comment: Well I've got theos on my device and code on it since I do not own a Mac. I just want to make a simple app to practice coding. Do you have a solution of my problem?